# How to add a sign in page using default google sign in App Engine and fetch and store some user data in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on an App Engine Project.

I need to add a user sign in functionality before accessing the app. I read different documentations and questions and found that App Engine comes with the support of providing user sign in option using the Google Sign In.

As of now, I didn't use the sign in functionality in my application. If I add this feature, how can I redirect the user to the home page after sign in and ensure that each part of the application is accessible only when the user signs in?

Also, I need to store some information like the username which the user enters during sign-in process into the datastore and use it later in my application.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it you simply want the user to have to sign into their Google account before they're able to access any page in your app. This can be done pretty easily in your web.xml file by adding (under your servlet mapping):

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will prompt the user to sign into their Google account before taking them to whatever page they were trying to access.

Comment: Thanks, it answered part of my question...! Can you also suggest how can I get the user data such as its username or email address which the user used for signing in? I need to create a kind of the corresponding name and store into datastore.

Comment: Take a look at User Objects and the get_current_user() method: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which front end approach/framework you are using in your "App Engine project" or "application"

If it is a web application and you use Google Endpoints, you should have a look at this tutorial which shows how to secure endpoints.

https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-5-7cece01570f#.7n6ug9lmi and https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-6-e9d72635d94b#.mlbffkqr2

In order to store the user name entered by the user, you just have to get it from the User object that is injected in the Endpoints method and save it in the datastore (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/parameter-and-return-types#injected_types)

Comment: Thanks... I am using Java Servlets to manage my web application frontend and Eclipse Mars as my development environment